# Incompatible JavaHl library loaded

Tags: eclipse, svn, ubuntu, subclipse

I'm having a problem with Subclipse and the JavaHL library. Subclipse it gives the error:

> Incompatible JavaHL library loaded.  1.8.x or later required.

I am using Ubuntu desktop 12.04 32 bit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Subclipse 1.10.x requires SVN 1.8.x libraries.  This Wiki page explains it.

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

I think Ubuntu 12.04 comes with SVN 1.6.x.  So you probably want Subclipse 1.8.x and SVNKit, or else get Subversion and JavaHL from someone other than Ubuntu.  See here:

http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for your reply i did the same as it mention in above link but still no work and getting same error.

Comment: You are going to have to provide more details about what you did or tried to do.

Comment: Now its working fine, this link is really helpful I need to have Subclipse 1.8.x..finally done with it, thanks for you help.

Comment: Fyi, Subclipse 1.8 requires JavaHL 1.7 or later.

Answer (score 3):

For me none of the methods found doesn't work. I have Ubuntu Xenial (16.04), eclipse 64b, java 64b, and libjava-svn packages installed, but it doesn't help. I've also tried manually download and install current Oracle java version and force eclipse to use it (-vm). 
Finally i went to [subclipse page](http://subclipse.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=p4wYuA) :

And in eclipse manually installed this:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.12.x

After eclipse has been restarted it finally found valid jni version.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that installing `Subversion JavaHL Native Library Adapter 1.9.3` from that source solved the issue. Turned out Ubuntu 16.04 has a newer library (1.9) than is the by default required one (1.8)

Answer (score 0):

Same error here, I've just installed `libsvnclientadapter-java` package and now it's working fine!

Comment: Where does this even place the libraries? I installed it as well but have no idea where to look for the JARs.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04, for me I just had to install the following package:

`$sudo apt-get install subversion`

`$sudo apt-get install libapache2-svn`

After that I just restart eclipse and everything was fine.