# Problems to installa Subeclipse Eclipse plugin, JavaHL Library missing

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink

I have installed **Eclipse Kepler** on my **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** system and I am finding many difficulties installing **Subclipse plugin** on it.

I have do the following steps:

1. I am go into **Help ---> Install New Software** and I have add this repository URL: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x/ for **Subeclipse plugin**
2. Now appear to me the possibilities to dowload some packages divided into the following categories: **Subeclipse** and **SVNKit**, I have installed all the packages that are into these categories.

Now I would import in my workspace a project that are on a SVN server and I do the following operation:

**File ---> New ---> Project --> SVN ---> Checkout Projects from SVN ---> click on Next button ---> Create a new repository location ---> here in the URL field I insert the address of my SVN repository and click on the Next button**

So now appear to me the following error screen that say to me that I have not the required **JavaHL Library**:

[image]

The error message say that:

```
Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

I have tryied to download it from the Eclipse "Install new software" wizard but seems not exist here...

What can I do to install it on my Ubuntu 12.04 system?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question, but I would try using subversive, available from the Kepler update site.  I have not had these kinds of problems with subversive.

Answer (score 4):

From [Subclipse: Wiki: JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL#head-bb1dd50f9ec2f0d8c32246430c00e237d27a04fe)

**How do I get JavaHL?**

- In Debian/Ubuntu the package name is `libsvn-java` so you can just run this command to install the library:

  - `$ apt-get install libsvn-java # Use sudo in Ubuntu`
- Next, find the path where the JavaHL library is installed, as you will need to know this path for the following instructions:

  - `$ find / -name libsvnjavahl-1.so # Use sudo in Ubuntu`

*Although the library is installed, you still have to tell Java (when used for Eclipse) where to find it. The JVM on Linux does not look in a lot of the standard locations to find the libraries. (This could obviously change in the future.) For example, 32-bit Debian/Ubuntu uses a standard location of /usr/lib/jni for libraries to be used from Java. However, the Oracle JVM does not currently look in this location. The easiest way to tell Java where to find the JavaHL library is to specify the following when starting the JVM:*

```
-Djava.library.path=</path/to/library>
```

Example:

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni
```

*Eclipse provides its own mechanism for providing this setting. Eclipse comes with a file named eclipse.ini. This file is looked at when the Eclipse launcher starts the JVM and appends settings to the JVM when launching it. Specifically, you should see a line that says "-vmargs". Add a newline after this line and insert the above line to pass the setting the JVM needs. Each argument needs to be on its own line, so be sure to add a new line and then put the entire string above on its own line.*

Here is an example of this file from Eclipse 3.4:

```
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-framework
plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.0.v20080605-1900.jar
-vmargs
-Djava.library.path=/opt/CollabNet_Subversion/lib
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

Comment: I prefer not using JavaHL to avoid the effort but nice extensive answer :-)

Comment: mmm ok but now give me this new error after that I have execute this procedure: Incompatible JavaHL library loaded.  1.8.x or later required.

Comment: @AndreaNobili thats because Subclipse 1.10.x requires SVN 1.8.x libraries and Ubuntu 12.04 comes with SVN 1.6.x. Here is a solution to your new error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929229/incompatible-javahl-library-loaded

Answer (score 3):

The JavaHL library needed for the adapter does not come with Ubuntu. Use the `SVNKit Client Adapter` instead. See http://www.rarejava.com/blog/2011/05/installing-subclipse-with-svnkit

But as Andrew commented I would also recommend using Subversive instead. Although you need one of the adapters for Subversive too if I remember correctly.

Comment: Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: @tokam what are you trying to say?

Comment: The linked website is offline.

Comment: @tokam oh, too bad. Let's hope it comes up again.